# pandas dataframe group by a column and based on count update another column rows individually

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Input dataframe

```
data = {

'org_id' :[79,80,21,36,40,7,10,9,12,24],
'r_id' : [79,80,20,20,20,7,7,9,12,12],
'Type_id' : ['P','P','C','C','C','P','C','P','P','C'],
'grp_id': ['g54','g55','g13','g13','g13','g6','g6','g7','g8','g8']

}
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
df2


  Out[271]: 
       org_id  r_id Type_id grp_id
    0      79    79       P    g54
    1      80    80       P    g55
    2      21    20       C    g13
    3      36    20       C    g13
    4      40    20       C    g13
    5       7     7       P     g6
    6      10     7       C     g6
    7       9     9       P     g7
    8      12    12       P     g8
    9      24    12       C     g8
```

output dataframe

data = {

```
'org_id' :[79,80,21,36,40,7,10,9,12,24],
'r_id' : [79,80,20,20,20,7,7,9,12,12],
'Type_id' : ['C','C','C','C','C','P','C','C','P','C'],
'grp_id': ['g54','g55','g13','g13','g13','g6','g6','g7','g8','g8']

}

df3 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
df3
```

Expected output:

```
    Out[270]: 
   org_id  r_id Type_id grp_id
0      79    79       C    g54
1      80    80       C    g55
2      21    20       C    g13
3      36    20       C    g13
4      40    20       C    g13
5       7     7       P     g6
6      10     7       C     g6
7       9     9       C     g7
8      12    12       P     g8
9      24    12       C     g8
```

Based on the group count on column(grp_id) if the value is equal to one(1) then change the type_id to 'C'

Eg. g54 and g55 has only one occurrence, hence the type_id='C', g13 and g6 appears more than once , so I don't change that type. Thanking you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) with mask by [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) with `keep=False` for all duplicates:

```
#get all duplicated rows by grp_id
mask = df2['grp_id'].duplicated(keep=False)
#compare counts by not equal 1
#mask = df2.groupby('grp_id')['grp_id'].transform('size').ne(1)
df2['Type_id'] = df2['Type_id'].where(mask, 'C')

print (df2)
   org_id  r_id Type_id grp_id
0      79    79       C    g54
1      80    80       C    g55
2      21    20       C    g13
3      36    20       C    g13
4      40    20       C    g13
5       7     7       P     g6
6      10     7       C     g6
7       9     9       C     g7
8      12    12       P     g8
9      24    12       C     g8
```